# Add "run in terminal" option in Nautilus actions configuration tool

Tags: command-line, configuration, tools, nautilus-actions

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 and Nautilus Actions Configuration Tool 3.1.4. When ever I select the option 'run in terminal' in execution tab...it doesn't work. The comand i'm running shows a progress bar which is not visible using any other option. How can I fix this?

[image: nautilus actions config tool - execution tab]

Comment: Why do you want to do it with "run in a terminal" option? Do you want to see the output of your action? And it would be better, if you could let me know the command which you are trying to execute.

Comment: i'm trying to use rsync which display's a progress bar that needs a terminal

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In nautilus-actions tool, go to Edit > Preferences > Runtime Execution. In the "command pattern" field, enter: `gnome-terminal -x sh -c COMMAND`

Then your commands/scripts will execute in the terminal just fine. Hope this helps someone!

Comment: What if I want to run only specific options in the terminal?

Answer (score 2):

Add a new action in Nautilus Actions Configuration Tool, called "Run in Terminal".

The relevant command is simple:

```
gnome-terminal -x %f
```

So, add that under *Command* tab

[image]

To always **keep the terminal open** when running this action, use a Gnome Terminal profile with that setting: In `gnome-terminal`, Edit-Preferences, select 'Profiles' tab, add new profile and call it "hold", and under 'Command' tab check to keep it open:

[image]

then add `--profile=hold` to the gnome-terminal parameters

[image]

(On how to add that setting in other terminal emulators, see [THIS](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/205602/32012) answer.)

Then, under *Mimetypes* tab, add `application/*`.

[image]

Be sure that under the 'Action' tab of Nautilus Actions Configuration Tool, you have selected the setting for displaying the option in context menu of selection.

[image]

Save.