# How to run executables directly from nautilus?

Tags: nautilus, executable, execute-command

When I write C codes in geany and the build and then run the program from there using the buttons there, it works fine. Again I can run the compiled executables using `./file_name` command from terminal emulator. But when I double click on the executable from nautilus, nothing happens. I have also checked "Allow executing the file as a program" from the properties menu. But the problem still exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to run executable files from nautilus, you just have to double click on them.

The reason why you don't see anything is probably because the programs you are making are terminal applications (without a Graphical User Interface) and thus are run on the background, without anywhere to display their output.

So, while the program itself is run, you do not see the result of it.

If an application has a Graphical User Interface then you will have absolutely no problem in running it by double clicking it.

What I do in order to solve this problem, is download the package `nautilus-open-terminal` (requires relogin to enable it) which adds a "open terminal here" option to nautilus.

So, whenever I want to run something from the current directory with doesn't have a GUI, I open a terminal at the current directory and I run it through the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

It's most probably printing things on the command-line and that won't show the output when you double-click and run from nautilus. So every time you run the program from nautilus, it is indeed executing, but not showing output since it is not a terminal.

You can use the [Nautilus Actions Configuration Tool](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/nautilus-actions/) to set running such programs from `gnome-terminal`.

If you're facing problems with getting NACT to run stuff from the `gnome-terminal`, you might want to refer to this question - ["Run in terminal" option in Nautilus Actions Configuration Tool doesn't work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/278520/run-in-terminal-option-in-nautilus-actions-configuration-tool-doesnt-work)